# Get the 'Active' attribute of and object

Tags: javascript, oop, object, attributes

today I'm starting on OO in javascript, I've created 3 blocks ( an object each)

I append the, to the html code after creating them, but **when I click on one of this objects it doesn't returns me the ACTIVE attribute.**

HTML container where I append the blocks :

```
<div id="llens"> </div>
```

*JQUERY:*

```
 $(document).ready(function() {



/**********************************  CREAtING OBJECT--> BLOC  *************************************************/




function bloc(nom, top, left ,amplada,altura , actiu ){
    this.nom=nom;
    this.top = top+'px';
    this.left= left+'px';
    this.amplada= amplada+'px';
    this.altura = altura+'px';
    this.actiu = actiu;


}

function creaBloc (){
    bloc_profes = new bloc('bloc_profes', '40', '200','800','200','false');
    bloc_text = new bloc('bloc_text','100', '200','800','100','false');
    bloc_alumnes = new bloc('bloc_alumnes', '200', '200','800','200','false');

    var bloc1 = $('<div class="bloc professor" id="'+bloc_profes.nom+'" style="top:'+bloc_profes.top+'; left:'+bloc_profes.left+'; width:'+bloc_profes.amplada+'; height:'+bloc_profes.altura+' " >');
    var bloc2= $('<div class="bloc text" id="'+bloc_text.nom+'" style="top:'+bloc_text.top+'; left:'+bloc_text.left+'; width:'+bloc_text.amplada+'; height:'+bloc_text.altura+' " >');
    var bloc3 = $('<div class="bloc alumne" id="'+bloc_alumnes.nom+'" style="top:'+bloc_alumnes.top+'; left:'+bloc_alumnes.left+'; width:'+bloc_alumnes.amplada+'; height:'+bloc_alumnes.altura+' " >');

    $('#llens').append(bloc1);
    $('#llens').append(bloc2);
    $('#llens').append(bloc3);
}

creaBloc();

        $(".bloc").click(function (event) {
        event.stopPropagation();

         bloc_nom = event.target.id; // New selected target

         console.log('NOM: '+bloc_nom);
         console.log('Actiu? : '+bloc_nom.actiu);


         });


    });
```

Comment: `event.target.id` just returns the id (as text), so `.actiu` on the id (=string) will return undefined.

Comment: btw. you should use `false` instead of `"false"`

Comment: @roberkules so any way to get the id when I click ?  How to associate a object to a DOM Object ? I thing that's where I get lost....   Anyways thanx ! ;)

Comment: @bfavaretto's answer should get you in the right direction.

Comment: @roberkules yes ! Sorry I didn't see it :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing tying your objects and DOM elements together. Considering your current structure, you could wrap all bloc objects in another object:

```
// On the top scope inside document.ready
var blocs = {};
```

Then create the blocs and append to that object:

```
blocs['bloc_profes'] = new bloc('bloc_profes', 40, 200, 800, 200, false);
blocs['bloc_text'] = new bloc('bloc_text', 100, 200, 800, 100, false);
blocs['bloc_alumnes'] = new bloc('bloc_alumnes', 200, 200, 800, 200, false);
```

So you'll be able to do this in the event handler:

```
$(".bloc").click(function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    var bloc_nom = this.id;
    var bloc = blocs[bloc_nom];
    console.log('Actiu? : ' + bloc.actiu);
});
```

---

Another approach is to use jQuery `.data` to tie them together directly in `creaBloc`:

```
bloc1.data('bloc', bloc_profes);
```

Then in the event listener you do:

```
$(".bloc").click(function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    var bloc = $(this).data('bloc');
    console.log('Actiu? : ' + bloc.actiu);
});
```

Comment: @roberkules Thanks for the sanitization! I din't actually look at what I was pasting.